# Schrödinger equation compared to Gauss law for electrostatic polarization?

Tags: electrostatics, schroedinger-equation, gauss-law, polarization, dipole

Consider an electrically neutral isolated metallic sphere in vacuum. Suppose we approach this sphere with a negative point charge. When the point charge is close enough, the electronic density on the sphere will spatially redistribute such that a local positive charge is induced near the negative point charge.

Calculating the spatial redistribution of the charge on the sphere by assuming a constant potential on the sphere and solving (only the first) Maxwell equations (or Gauss law) is a standard problem in electrostatics, showing how a neutral object can be "polarized".

Now consider a Hydrogen atom in vacuum. Solving Schrödinger's equation for the electronic density implies a spherical distribution of the electronic charge (in the ground state), which can be roughly thought of as a neutral sphere. When we approach this Hydrogen with a bare proton, or a positive point charge, we can solve Schrödinger equation and calculate the electronic distribution on the Hydrogen. By experience, we know that this calculation will indeed result in a changed electronic density that minimizes the interaction energy with the point charged, it will be "polarized".

Can you make qualitative statements on the comparison that should be expected from the two approaches?

Strictly speaking, the two settings I described are a bit different, because in the metallic state the electronic density does not correspond to a spherical cloud around a positive point charge. But in first approximation we could ignore this detail.

Comment: That analysis can be found in Griffiths book on QM, in the chapter analysing the Hydrogen molecule ion (2 protons and 1 electron).

Comment: I am assuming the distance between the hydrogen and the proton to be large enough to avoid bonding, but small enough to induce polarization. I would have a look again at Griffith, but I studied that book and I do not recall that polarization was treated.